# Bash Linux Control de espacio

Tags: linux, bash

como les va, todo bien?
Necesito armar un script que controle el espacio de un FS en particular el cual tiene varios directorios. Por otro lado, sera necesario que envie un mail indicando el porcentaje de ocupacion de cada Directorio andentro de ese FS, sobre el total de ocupacion indicando que porcentaje del espacio total ocupa cada directorio.
Lo que estoy necesitando particularmente es como puedo realizar esos calculos.

Por ejemplo, detallo nombre del FS y lo que ocupa cada directorio

```
FS : /archivos (5T)
Contenido: /archivos/test/ (1T)
Contenido: /archivos/garbage/ (10 Megas)
Contenido: /archivos/log/ (2T)
Contenido: /archivos/solaris/ (5 kilobytes)

lo que necesitaria es que me muestre algo asi

/archivos -> Ocupoa 5Teras, ocupado 90%
/archivos/test/ (1T), ocupa el 20% del FS /archivos
/archivos/garbage/ (10 Megas), ocupa el 1% del FS /archivos
/archivos/log/ (2T), ocupa el 30% del FS /archivos
/archivos/solaris/ (5 kilobytes), ocupa el 1% del FS /archivos
```

Como puedo hacer para obtener esos datos y calcular el porcentaje tal lo necesito?

Esto debe ser en bash

Comment: supongo que usando wc y metiendo los valores en variables.

Comment: A qué te refieres con controlar el espacio? Sobre el mail, qué cliente piensas utilizar? Te sugiero revisar las preguntas sobre expresiones regulares en este sitio para leer ese archivo.

Comment: sendmail, pero igualmente yo se como enviar por mail, yo necesito como realizar los calculos en bash para lo que necesito, obteniendo los valores necesarios

Comment: Intenta revisar sobre expresiones regulares para extraer datos. Puedes utilizar grep o awk para obtener cada tamaño en una variable. Ya sobre ese total puedes aplicar la regla de tres: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regla_de_tres

Comment: Pero también necesitarás hacer conversiones según lo que quiera el usuario, osea a MB, GB, B, o TB. Puedes buscar sobre cómo hacer una función de conversión o tener una unidad de conversión base, y ya sobre esta puedes operar

Comment: Tu regex puede dividir cada registro en dos partes. Una que lee la ruta y otra que guarda el tamaño. Y ya la proporcion la imprimes con la regla de tres.

Comment: `df -h` `du -h` y algo q verifique en el `/etc/fstab` a ver si cada carpeta está realmente en el mismo fs, calculos: `$ bc <<<"valor/total*100"` y lo pasas por [`numfmt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html#Possible-units_003a) si es por alertas "uyuyuy" :  monit https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SPACE-USAGE-TEST

Comment: @aloMalbarez Yo entendí que ya tenía esos datos salvo los cálculos del porcentaje. Por lo que no sería necesario un "df" o "du", sino sólo algo que presupusiera esos datos como los que te pone como ejemplo. No sé si eso es lo que el OP quería decir.

Comment: @Cuauhtli menciono herramientas mas que nada para dar alternativas en cómo encarar el requerimiento "control de espacio en linux/bash"; un `mount --bind` puede hacer necesario un `du -x` ; tal vez un `df -h` es todo lo que necesita; bash no maneja decimales asi q para porcentajes va mejor `bc`; convertir entre kilo mega giga puede ser confuso si se mezclan potencias de 10 con potencias de 2 ( `Kilo:10^3, Mega:10^6 / Kilo:2^10, Mega:2^20` ) etc... por otro lado monit ademas de avisar puede correr un script onda [dead man switch](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hombre_muerto)

Comment: @aloMalbarez, creo que es porque la pregunta está muy abierta y extraña. Dice que tiene una cosa, que le pidieron otra, pero que quiere otra, y además menciona una que ya tiene...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu consulta no es trivial (de hecho yo le pondría precio) y requiere de algo de esfuerzo de la mano de obra de un ingeniero especializado. Pero igual trataré de contestar tu post solo para pulir mis skills.

Lo que se necesita es procesar línea por línea, cadena por cadena, practicar múltiples extracciones con expresiones regulares, homologar formatos, operar con unidades comunes, luego crear una plantilla para el resultado:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

options_reader() {
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]
    do
        case "$1" in
            --filename | -f )
                shift
                export _filename="$1"
                shift
                ;;
            --filename=* )
                export _filename="${1#*=}"
                shift
                ;;
            *)  
                shift
                ;;
        esac
    done
}
normalize_size_to_bytes() {
    local -r size="$1"
    local -r normalized_suffix="$2"
    local bytes="$(echo "${size}${normalized_suffix}" | numfmt --from=auto)"
    echo "$bytes"
}
normalize_size_suffix() {
    local -r size_suffix="$1"
    local -r first_size_letter="${size_suffix:0:1}"
    local -ru normalized_size_suffix="$first_size_letter"
    echo "$normalized_size_suffix"
}
extract_size_part() {
    local -r record="$1"
    local -r size_regex='(?<=\().*(?=\))'
    
    local -r size_part="$(echo "$record" | grep -Po "$size_regex")"
    echo "$size_part"
}
extract_size_number() {
    local -r size_part="$1"
    local -r number_regex='\d+'
    
    local -ri size_number="$(echo "$size_part" | grep -Po "$number_regex")"
    echo "$size_number"
}
extract_size_suffix() {
    local -r size_part="$1"
    local -r suffix_regex='[^\d ]+'
    
    local -r size_number="$(echo "$size_part" | grep -Po "$suffix_regex")"
    echo "$size_number"
}
extract_pathname() {
    local -r record="$1"
    local -r filename_regex='(?<=\/).*(?=\/)'
    
    local -r filename_match="$(echo "$record" | grep -Po "$filename_regex")"
    local -r filename="/$filename_match/"
    echo "$filename"
}
get_bytes_per_row() {
    local -r row="$1"
    local -r size_part="$(extract_size_part "$row")"
    
    local -ri size_number="$(extract_size_number "$size_part")"
    local -r size_suffix="$(extract_size_suffix "$size_part")"
    
    local normalized_size_suffix="$(normalize_size_suffix "$size_suffix")"
    
    local total_bytes="$(normalize_size_to_bytes "$size_number" "$normalized_size_suffix")"
    echo "$total_bytes"
}
calculate_percentage_per_size() {
    local size_in_bytes="$1"
    local percentage="$((size_in_bytes*100/total_bytes))"
    echo "$percentage"
}
get_bytes_per_row() {
    local row="$1"
    
    local size_part="$(extract_size_part "$row")"
    
    local size_number="$(extract_size_number "$size_part")"
    local size_suffix="$(extract_size_suffix "$size_part")"
    
    local normalized_size_suffix="$(normalize_size_suffix "$size_suffix")"
    
    local total_bytes="$(normalize_size_to_bytes "$size_number" "$normalized_size_suffix")"

    echo "$total_bytes"
}
extract_fsname() {
    local record="$1"
    local fs_name_regex='(?<=\/)\w+(?=\s*\()'
    
    local fs_name_match="$(echo "$record" | grep -Po "$fs_name_regex")"
    local fs_name="/$fs_name_match"
    echo "$fs_name"
}
create_size_with_suffix_normalized() {
    local -r row="$1"
    local -r size_part="$(extract_size_part "$row")"
    local -r size_suffix="$(extract_size_suffix "$size_part")"
    local -ri size_number="$(extract_size_number "$size_part")"
    local -r normalized_size_suffix="$(normalize_size_suffix "$size_suffix")"
    
    echo "${size_number}${normalized_size_suffix}"
}
print_fs_info() {
    local -r first_row="$1"
    local -ri percentage_occupied="$2"

    local -r fs_name="$(extract_fsname "$first_row")"
    local -r size_with_suffix="$(create_size_with_suffix_normalized "$first_row")"
    
    echo "$fs_name -> Ocupa $size_with_suffix, ocupado $percentage_occupied%"
}
process_row() {
    local -r row="$1"
    
    local -r path_name="$(extract_pathname "$row")"
    local -r size_with_suffix="$(create_size_with_suffix_normalized "$row")"
    local -ri size_in_bytes="$(normalize_size_to_bytes "$size_with_suffix")"
    local -ri percentage="$(calculate_percentage_per_size "$size_in_bytes")"
    
    ((percentage_occupied = percentage_occupied + percentage))
    
    local -r processed_row="$path_name (${size_with_suffix}), ocupa el ${percentage}% del FS $fs_name"
    result_info+=("$processed_row")  
}
process_file() {
    declare -r _file="$1"
    declare -i percentage_occupied=0
    declare -a result_info
    declare -r first_row="$(head -n 1 "$_file")"
    declare -r fs_name="$(extract_fsname "$first_row")"
    declare -ri total_bytes="$(get_bytes_per_row "$first_row")"

    set +m
    shopt -s lastpipe
    
    tail -n +2 "$_file" \
    | while read -r row || [ -n "$row" ]; do
        process_row "$row"
    done 
    
    print_fs_info "$first_row" "$percentage_occupied"
    printf '%s\n' "${result_info[@]}"
}

main() {
    options_reader $@
    process_file "$_filename"
}

main $@
```

Si al archivo `sizes.txt` le pones el siguiente contenido:

```
FS : /archivos (10T)
Contenido: /archivos/test/ (8T)
Contenido: /archivos/garbage/ (10 Megas)
Contenido: /archivos/log/ (500G)
Contenido: /archivos/log2/ (500G)
Contenido: /archivos/solaris/ (5 kilobytes)
```

Al correr el programa obtienes:

```
$ ./size_processor.sh --filename=sizes.txt
/archivos -> Ocupa 10T, ocupado 90%
/archivos/test/ (8T), ocupa el 80% del FS /archivos
/archivos/garbage/ (10M), ocupa el 0% del FS /archivos
/archivos/log/ (500G), ocupa el 5% del FS /archivos
/archivos/log2/ (500G), ocupa el 5% del FS /archivos
/archivos/solaris/ (5K), ocupa el 0% del FS /archivos
```

Si crees que esto es mucho código para un solo archivo, puedes separar las funciones y llamarlos con `source` en el inicio.

Aquí tienes unas cuantas pruebas unitarias con la suite de `bats`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats

source "./size_processor.sh"

@test "It should normalize the size suffix" {
  # Given
  bad_suffix="mEgaBites"
  expected_suffix="M"
  
  # When
  result_suffix="$(normalize_size_suffix "$bad_suffix")"

  # Then
  [ "$result_suffix" = "$expected_suffix" ]
}

@test "It should normalize the size to bytes" {
  # Given
  kb_size="10K"
  mb_size="10M"
  tb_size="10T"

  expected_kb_size="10000"
  expected_mb_size="10000000"
  expected_tb_size="10000000000000"
  
  # When
  result_kb_size="$(normalize_size_to_bytes "$kb_size")"
  result_mb_size="$(normalize_size_to_bytes "$mb_size")"
  result_tb_size="$(normalize_size_to_bytes "$tb_size")"

  # Then
  [ "$result_kb_size" -eq "$expected_kb_size" ]
  [ "$result_mb_size" -eq "$expected_mb_size" ]
  [ "$result_tb_size" -eq "$expected_tb_size" ]
}

@test "It should extract the size part from the record" {
  # Given
  record="stuff /path1/path2/   (34TeRaBites)"
  expected_size_part="34TeRaBites"
  
  # When
  actual_size_part="$(extract_size_part "$record")"

  # Then
  [ "$actual_size_part" = "$expected_size_part" ]
}

@test "It should extract the size number from the size part" {
  # Given
  size_part="90Kilobaits"
  expected_size_number=90
  
  # When
  actual_size_number="$(extract_size_number "$size_part")"

  # Then
  [ "$actual_size_number" -eq "$expected_size_number" ]
}

@test "It should extract the path name from the record" {
  # Given
  record="Contenido: /path 1/path 2/path 3/ (10 MegaBaits)"
  expected_path="/path 1/path 2/path 3/"
  
  # When
  actual_path="$(extract_pathname "$record")"

  # Then
  [ "$actual_path" = "$expected_path" ]
}
```

Y al correrlas tenemos:

```
$ bats tests_size_processor.bats
 ✓ It should normalize the size suffix
 ✓ It should normalize the size to bytes
 ✓ It should extract the size part from the record
 ✓ It should extract the size number from the size part
 ✓ It should extract the path name from the record

5 tests, 0 failures
```

## Update mayor

Cree:

- Un repositorio con el proyecto,
- Con un árbol de archivos para hacer las tareas de extraccion y cálculo modularizando y encapsulando todo,
- También con algunos tests unitarios con `bats`,
- Con el enfoque de *acceptance test-driven development*
- Un pipeline de CI/CD de Gitlab para tests y deploy

Este es el repositorio: [Repositorio](https://gitlab.com/mrc_es/bash_size_processor)

Este es el pequeño pipeline de CI/CD: [CI/CD Pipeline](https://gitlab.com/mrc_es/bash_size_processor/-/pipelines/674291219)

Un ejemplo de como pasa los stages el pequeñisimo DAG:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y del job como resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que no se debería es hacerle el trabajo al OP sin que haya puesto, al menos, un ejemplo de lo que ha intentado.

Comment: Ei, lo sé. Sólo que me pareció buena idea repasar mis conocimientos de bash, unit testing, acceptance test-driven development, SOLID principles (solo open-closed, y single responsability), y ci/cd (estor preparando un repo al respecto). En si, sólo espero que cierren esta pregunta

Comment: Sí, tu respuesta está genial en cuanto a conocimientos.

Comment: que pedazo de respuesta lpm! que despilfarro de conocimientos! Debería ir a la wiki.